# MATLAB: Read raw data from an usb (generic) input device

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've an usb IMU (inertial measurement unit) for videogame applications and Windows detects it as usb input device and loads it in the HID devices section (Control Panel). Since it has not any COM port allocation, how can i read its raw data by matlab (or simulink) ? I tried with Instrument Control Toolbox but it requires a COM port adress. Thanks.

Comment: There is probably some kind of library to access the data. Please link the datasheet or product page.

Comment: the product is the Vuzix Wrap Tracker. It is an IMU for virtual reality eyewear. They gave me only a software for calibration (VR Manager). http://www.vuzix.com/UKSITE/support/downloads_drivers.html

Comment: There is an SDK available on the home page.

Comment: Yes, but i should use it in matlab. How can i exploit it? Alternatively, i found the physichtoolbox for read from a HID device but i do not how use it.

Comment: You may use C, C++ (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html), Java (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html) or .net (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html) within Matlab. (no claim to completeness)